# How do you precisely transfer the slope of your floor to the cut line of the wall tiles you need to install near the floor?

Tags: tiling

In the below picture
-yellow is a wall
-grey is the floor
-white rectangles = tiles (1x2 in this example)

Is there an ingenious way to exactly transfer the floor slope (exaggerated here) to the tiles so that you can tile them to the exact size and make then follow the contour for the floor like 1/8" above (assume that is still a straight line but sloped, hence the problem)

there will be no baseboard in that area the wall tile will meet the floor tile and I will caulk the joint line (1/8")

[image]

Comment: place a wide board against the wall ... use it to draw a line on the tiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You scribe it using a compass or block. Space the tile up a bit so the top edge is still parallel with the installed tiles. Set the compass to the widest point, say the left lower corner of your illustration as the full width of tile then trace the floor with the compass moving it to the right. You can use a block of wood or scrap of tile etc.